# checking if a directory is created or not, fails?

Tags: android, file-io, toast

I'm trying to create a directory, and i'm checking whether it is created successfully or not but displaying a text on the screen, but nothing to be displayed.

Java code:

```
public void createDirectory() {
    try {
        String strDirectory = "test";
        boolean success = ( new File(strDirectory)).mkdir();
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Directory "+strDirectory+" created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error creating directory");
    }
}
```

Comment: no Toast appearing seems to indicate that it's doing neither the "if" nor the "else"... which means there's an exception, and it's doing the Log.e(...). Could you post the logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `.show()` end of `Both` Toast....

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Directory "+strDirectory+" created", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add uses-permission write external storage to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I actually don't know where it's trying to create the directory since you are not qualifying the entire path. what are you trying to do?

If you are trying to create it on the SD card, do this,

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt");
```

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Note that this file will be readable by all apps.

If you are trying to create a file that's private to the app, do this,

```
OutputStream os = context.openFileOutput("myfile.txt");
```

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Note that this method is reserved for small files as it uses the internal storage which is limited on many devices.

Finally, always print the stack trace,

```
Log.e("mytag", "some message", e);
```

9 times out of ten, this will point you directly to the problem.